# Date Labels on X Axis Not Showing For Each Column

Tags: datetime, graph, highcharts, label

I've got a graph I've been working on a bit yesterday and this morning on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XJES3/6/

If you look you'll see the xAxis labels for the columns are not always showing up.  I'm sure there's a setting somewhere that forces them to always show or possibly a way to set the interval but I'm at a loss finding it in the API docs so far. Would love if someone could point me in the right directions.

Thanks a bunch.

Highcharts code below:

```
var go_local_scriblio_authority_history = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'go-local-scriblio-authority-history',
        type: 'column'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled:false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            step: 1,
            rotation: -90,
            style: {
                fontSize: '10px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
                color: '#629bc0'
            },
            x: 3,
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value).toUpperCase();
            }
        },
        reversed: false,
        lineColor: '#ffffff',
        tickColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        labels: false,
        title: false,
        gridLineColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    legend: false,
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<strong>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', this.x) + ':</strong> ' + this.y;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Article Counts by Month',
        color: '#629bc0',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2013,  2, 1),2], [Date.UTC(2013,  1, 1),22], [Date.UTC(2012,  12, 1),11], [Date.UTC(2012,  11, 1),22], [Date.UTC(2012,  10, 1),28], [Date.UTC(2012,  9, 1),37], [Date.UTC(2012,  8, 1),38], [Date.UTC(2012,  7, 1),60], [Date.UTC(2012,  6, 1),87], [Date.UTC(2012,  5, 1),53], [Date.UTC(2012,  4, 1),62], [Date.UTC(2012,  3, 1),51], [Date.UTC(2012,  2, 1),29], [Date.UTC(2012,  1, 1),54], [Date.UTC(2011,  12, 1),50], [Date.UTC(2011,  11, 1),49], [Date.UTC(2011,  10, 1),45], [Date.UTC(2011,  9, 1),40], [Date.UTC(2011,  8, 1),42], [Date.UTC(2011,  7, 1),50], [Date.UTC(2011,  6, 1),48], [Date.UTC(2011,  5, 1),57], [Date.UTC(2011,  4, 1),44], [Date.UTC(2011,  3, 1),52]]
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            pointWidth: 10,
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a tickInterval:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval

http://jsfiddle.net/XJES3/7/

```
tickInterval:86400*30 * 1000, //30 days, in miliseconds
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Of course the answer was staring me in the face the whole time. :)